# Generate XML from Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a question about generating `XML` files from `SQL server (2005)`
I am using this code:

```
Select Emp_Id,Emp_Name from tblEmployee Where Emp_Id < 3
For XML AUTO,ELEMENTS
```

what I need to add to save this file in my hard drive with a specific name (`DDMMYYYYHHMM`)?

Comment: What are you using the query the database? [Management Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio), [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx), or some other application?

Answer (score 0):

```
EXEC master..XP_CmdShell 'BCP "Select Emp_Id,Emp_Name from tblEmployee Where Emp_Id < 3
For XML AUTO,ELEMENTS" queryout "c:\sample.xml" -c -T'
```

Comment: `xp_cmdshell` is disabled by default in SQL Server 2005+ versions. I don't think this is a situation that warrants enabling use of this procedure.

Comment: Yes Apocaliptica61.Its sql code and you should have permissions to use xp_cmdshell